# Android redirect to PWA

Tags: android, angular, google-chrome, progressive-web-apps

I am trying to redirect a user to an installed pwa automatically from chrome.  If I actually click the link it takes me to the pwa.  The link is to a different domain.  I am doing this since it was mentioned as a way to get the pwa to open since once your are on your domain in chrome, it assumes you want to stay there

```
<a id="pwaLink" href="https://example.com/pwa-success">link to pwa</a>
```

But when I try to use a method to automatically go to the url, it opens in chrome.

```
const element = document.getElementById('pwaLink');
element.click();
```

or

```
window.location.href = 'https://example.com/pwa-success'
```

Is there anyway to open a PWA from chrome?  I am hoping to not have to port this web app to an android app.

Answer (score 0):

It could be done when you provide a link that is under your pwa app scope.
And by using intent filter, If the user clicks on a link within an installed app to https://example.com/pwa-success, it would be caught by the intent and opened in the Progressive Web App.
For more information you should follow this [link](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/integration/webapks#using_scope_to_restrict_intent_filters)